# Android SDK Alternative Builds

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have a project that I'm working on ([Py4a](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/)) and I'm getting to the point where I wish to do two versions of the project... one with that downloads external files to run, and one with all the extra files included. 
There are pros and cons to both approaches, so I wanted to create two builds with mostly shared code,
My first attempt was to build the all-in-one version as a separate project that extends some classes of the original, and include the original project in the build path.
That compiles OK, but attempting to run this results in android loading in the original project as a dependency, and then failing to find the right classes on startup.
I can just copy the original project in total and modify, but that involves maintaining two sets of common code, which I don't want to do.
Is there a preferred approach or clever trick to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two obvious approaches for your situation:

1. Set up your 'core' code as a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html) and create two Android projects that make use of this library. This will allow you to maintain a single code base and at the same time provide project specific assets.
2. Create and `ant` task that will swap out specific pieces of code and/or assets based on a supplied configuration file.

The first option is definitely faster to set up and would be my first choice if you're not going to need more than just a couple of forks. The ant approach would potentially be more suitable for automating several builds in a row, and might be more flexible if you're going to work will a whole bunch of different, yet very similar forks.